Node.js server that streams an infinite silence sound switches to streaming mew audio data receiving an event, and then returns to silence
To create a Node.js server that streams an infinite silence sound, switches to streaming actual audio data upon receiving an event, and then returns to silence after the event's audio data ends, steps:
Plan:

Create an HTTP Server: Set up an HTTP server to handle incoming requests.
Infinite Silence Sound: Stream silence sound infinitely when the request starts.
Handle Audio Events: On receiving an appEvent.on('audio'), start streaming the audio data.
Return to Silence: Once the audio data ends, go back to streaming silence.
Keep the Request Open: Ensure the request stays open as long as the client is connected.

My Problem:

switching between file streaming doesn't work
silence sound always infinite play good but speech.mp3 doesn't work

How to resolve switching between file stream for pipe to response ?
This sevice must work like Radio
My Implementation:
import events from 'events'
import express from 'express'
import * as fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'
import { Readable } from 'stream'

const appEvent = new events.EventEmitter()

const silencePath = path.join(__dirname, 'silence.mp3')

// Helper function to generate silence sound
function silence() {
  const buffer = fs.readFileSync(silencePath) // Read file as Buffer
  return Readable.from(
    (async function* () {
      while (true) {
        yield buffer // Yield Buffer, not ArrayBuffer
      }
    })(),
  )
}

const app = express()

app.get('/stream', (req, res) => {
  // Example: Emit audio event to start streaming audio data
  setTimeout(() => {
    const speechPath = path.join(__dirname, 'speech.mp3')
    const speechStream = fs.createReadStream(speechPath)

    appEvent.emit('audio', speechStream)
  }, 5000)

  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
    'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
    Connection: 'keep-alive',
  })

  let silenceStream = silence()
  silenceStream.pipe(res)

  let audioStream: fs.ReadStream
  let audioInProgress = false

  // Listen for audio event to switch to the audio stream
  appEvent.on('audio', (audioDataStream: fs.ReadStream) => {
    if (audioInProgress) return // Ignore if already playing audio

    audioInProgress = true
    silenceStream.unpipe(res)

    audioStream = audioDataStream
    audioStream.pipe(res)

    // When the audio finishes, return to silence
    audioStream.on('end', () => {
      silenceStream = silence()
      silenceStream.pipe(res)
      audioInProgress = false
    })
  })

  req.on('close', () => {
    if (audioStream) {
      audioStream.unpipe(res)
      audioStream.destroy()
    }
    silenceStream.unpipe(res)
  })
})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log(`Client side start on 3000 port http://localhost:3000`))


I haven't used the node.js .pipe, unpipe etc. functions so not sure what's wrong with your code. But I've found using iterables easier to reason about.

To do this properly, you actually need to generate a continuous PCM audio stream and mix in your event samples (or replace the silent samples), and then go back to the silent stream.  And then, encode that audio stream with something like FFmpeg that can give you your continuous radio-like stream.
The reason for this stream is that you cannot simply concat chunks arbitrarily.  Each container format has its own specification you'd have to follow.  It's easier to do your mixing in PCM samples, which gives you more flexibility for how you encode and mux into containers later.

I was also trying something similar. Do you have any code examples how to do this?

do you have any example ?

How you do this specifically is up to you and your application.  It's pretty straightforward.  If you have a typical sample rate of say, 48 kHz, then you need 48,000 numbers (samples) per second, per channel (1 for mono, 2 for stereo, etc.).  I like to use floating point samples, so the sample value is (almost always) +/-1.0 full scale, with zero being the center.  The codec takes those values and encodes into the lossy format you probably need for streaming.  You can just pipe it to FFmpeg STDIN.

Anyway, your silent source is going to be nothing by 48,000 values of 0 per-second.  When you want to switch to something else, stop sending 0, and start sending the buffers from your source... like 0.234, 0.324, 0.555, -0.003, etc.

@Bard i have last question. How to stream openai tts to http response with silence sound ?
When do reqest to GET api/stream stream to response silence sound and when get new aduio on eventEmiter from openai tts (its can be mp3, wav, pcm, etc ...) stream to response keep alive and after end tts audio again stream silence sound and this operation infinite. Thank you very much Bard ) You very good

@Bard i think i must use OPUS audio format, because it's more light weight. Can you help me with this audio streaming like radio with silence infinite sound ?

@Eldiyar You can stream the output of something like FFmpeg's STDOUT directly to the HTTP client, and play it in an <audio> element.  And, if you need Opus, you just need to configure FFmpeg then to encode Opus.  (Though you'll need more than that if you want to play on the web... try using -f webm with your FFmpeg output parameters to ensure that you're wrapping Opus in the WebM/Matroska container, which is directly playable on the web.)  Also, Opus uses little-to-no bandwidth when encoding silence, so make sure your HTTP server isn't doing any extra buffering!
